# How can I be sure to update the data at the end of the application?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, optimization, updating

Currently I am updating the user data while they are using the application. This makes a lot of calls to the database.
I thought that I could gain in performance by performing only one update when the user leaves the application.
The problem is the following: What do I do if these last writes fail?
I know there is a completion block but I can't see how to restart the writes in it.
That's why for now I update the data as the app runs, even if it's more expensive.
How can I make sure that the data is updated when the user logs back in?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the swift function that you use to update user data is called `update_data()`. I see that you're using Firebase RealTimeDatabase, so you may have a block of code for completion. In that completion block you can add `error in` and there you can control what happens if there is an error writing the data, and call `update_data()` until there's no more errors. This may be very expensive for the device if there is no connection, or if the error will keep going forever.

However, the code should go like this:

```
func update_data(){
    Database.reference("path").setValue("Data you want to update", withCompletionBlock: {(error, reference) in
        if error != nil{
            //There was an error, try again
            update_data()
        }
    })
}
```

This doesn't seem to be a good practice as the code could run forever if there is always an error. But, you could check for error types in Firebase and deal with them independently. However, I've noticed that FB RealTimeDatabase keeps the request until the device has connection again (in case the error is network connection) as far as the user doesn't close the app completely (in such case, I think that there is no solution for your problem because when you completely close an app, all background tasks stop and if the writing fails, you can't run your application code with your app not running).

This last paragraph is all from my personal experience. I don't know if there are some other functionalities to deal with this problem. But, I hope it helps :). Please check your implementation in different cases (user with no connection, user with low connection, user with restricted access to your database. etc).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's exactly what I wanted to do but I was afraid of being in an infinite loop if the error persisted. 
But I'm interested in what you said about stopping the processes. If the user closes the application, then I couldn't even call this update_data() function and no update will be done ?

Comment: Exactly. However, there are other things you could do. For example, you could save the information on the device. If the online writing fails, then the information is stored on the device and you can recover it later when starting the app again (and try to write it online again). If you do so, you may add some code to delete the stored-in-device information when the information is already written to the online database.

Comment: I see. However I believed that by recording the data on the device directly, the user could have access to it if he had a jailbroken device for example. It is perhaps naive but by informing me on the principle of the jailbreak I arrived at this conclusion. It is not the case?

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert on security matters... But if you are saving data related to the user, he/she should know that and if they have access to it, what's the problem?

Also, security is never at 100%, so think of the balance between "security" and "functionality"